# hasManyThrough - Not returning the right data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an intermediate table titled

**app_services**

It consists of the following columns :

- app_service_id (PK)
- app_id (FK)
- service_id (FK)

The final table is the services table :

**Services**

- service_id (PK)
- service_name
- service_icon

I am trying a hasManyThrough on app_services. But it's returning the wrong results..

For app_id = 1 it has the service id's of 1 & 3. But it is returning back the service_id's pf 1 & 4.

In my app_model I am defining the relationship as follows :

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Service', 'App\AppService',
        'service_id', 'service_id', 'app_id'
    );
}
```

Now that looks right to me? Would someone mine checking if it's correct or not.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
}
```

Now, with such declaration of relationships Laravel “assumes” that pivot table name obeys the rules and is app_service.But, if it’s actually different (for example, it’s plural), you can provide it as a second parameter:

```
 public function services()
  {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service','app_services');
  }
```

'app_services' is an intermediate table name

Moreover, you can specify the actual field names of that pivot table, if they are different than default app_id and service_id. Then just add two more parameters – first, the current model field, and then the field of the model being joined

```
public function services()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service','app_services','app_id','service_id');
}
```

Now,using this relationship you can retrieved data

```
$app = App::find($app_id);
$app->services();
```

Comment: Hi, so would you put those on each model? Or in the one model

Comment: in app model you have to decklare service function and in service model you can declare app model

Comment: for more info you can visit http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: Thank you @Parth I really need to read up on this. It's a useful tool. But taking some getting my head around.